# Input styiling for verification

Tags: html, css

i was wondering if there is any meta of making a 4 code input field. The type that i mean is where the input is split in 4 parts. Illustrated bellow

[image]

i was thinking of just making 4 different inputs and styling them but there an easier or more effective way?

Comment: Are you added js or jquery into your input ?

Comment: how would that help?

Comment: Yes, Jquery or pure javascript will make a easier fill into your input

Comment: Making 4 inputs & styling them is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use React or Angular to build simple component of designed input and replicate them, simple and clean.